# how can parse xsd file and get all element and attribute in a xbrl xsd file?

Tags: java, xsd, xml-parsing, jaxb, xbrl

I want to parse a xsd file that extend from many xsd files and get all element and attribute in a domain model structure.
how can do this at the run time of project.
my project structure is jee.